# Excel Userform Textbox different text color

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a userform in Excel, I have a textbox with a large amount of text in. I need to have certain words in Bold and in Red color and the rest in standard black.

I can change the whole text color in the properties but not just certain words.

Is this possible and if so how would I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of TextBox is it you're using? Is it a FormControl or an ActiveX? Or the TextBox from the Insert ribbon?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you might want to replace your textbox control with the `InkEdit` control and provide options to the user to format the text (I tested with providing them with different buttons for making selected font bold/italics etc)

You will find this control in More Controls -> Microsoft InkEdit Control (I'm using Excel 2010)

A sample screenshot

[image]

Sample code that you might want to use for different buttons

```
ID1.SelBold = False
ID1.SelItalic = False
ID1.SelColor = vbRed
ID1.SelFontSize = 15
```